# Vertical LinearGradient with Android in Java

Tags: android

Here is the code I use:

```
Shader mShader0 = new LinearGradient(10 , 0,  66 ,0, 
    new int[] { Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE },
    null, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);  // CLAMP MIRROR REPEAT
pincel1.setShader(mShader0);

canvasG.drawRect(   0, 0,   30, 200, pincel1);
canvasG.drawRect(1250, 0, 1280, 200, pincel1);
canvasG.drawRect(1000, 0, 1030, 200, pincel1);
canvasG.drawRect( 200, 0,  230, 200, pincel1);
canvasG.drawRect( 250, 0,  280, 200, pincel1);

pincel1.setShader(null);
```

The result is that all the columns are different.

Why are not all the same? What is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because the `LinearGradient` is defined to start at `x=10`, end at `x=66` and repeat after that. When you assign the gradient to the paint, and draw different rectangles, the co-ordinates of the rectangles are used to determine which "part" of the gradient to draw. For example: a rectangle from `x=0` and `width=56` will contain your complete gradient. Any rectangle after that will repeat the pattern.

For more understanding, if you draw rectangles at `x={a, a+56, a+2*56, a+3*56 ..}` and `width<56` they will contain the same gradient pattern. I hope this explains why the above observations are correct.

Comment: Hello Amulya. 
Thank you for your response, the response that you have given me is perfect, first of all for the explanation, let me know as LinearGradient works, and secondly by the solution, which was what i was looking for. aa= 56
 bb = 10;
 mShader0 = new LinearGradient(bb , 0,  bb + aa, 0, 
   new int[] { Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE }, 
   null, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);  
 pincel1.setShader(mShader0);
 canvasG.drawRect (bb, 0,   bb + aa, 200, pincel1);
.......

This has been the solution that I have.